# Unable to get PFUser field

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to get the xp of the current user and display it in a label. The xp field of the user is equal to 252 but it is displaying 0. I can get other fields like email, username and password but can't get the value for the xp field. Code:

```
xpRequiredLabel.text = "\(PFUser.currentUser()!["XP"])/300 XP"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think the key is case sensitive. Is your column named `XP` or `xp` on Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression `PFUser.currentUser()!["XP"]` returns `AnyObject?`. You need to unwrap this optional and cast it to string. Try this:

```
let userXP = PFUser.currentUser()!["XP"] as! String
xpRequiredLabel.text = "\(userXP)/300 XP"
```

Or this (less error-prone):

```
if let userXP = PFUser.currentUser()?["XP"] as? String {
    xpRequiredLabel.text = "\(userXP)/300 XP"
}
```

#### Update

It turns out that you have to fetch the object from the server before accessing new properties. So, your code should look like:

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
user.fetch()
let userXP = ["XP"] as! Int // If you have "Number" as your column datatype
xpRequiredLabel.text = "\(userXP)/300 XP"
```

Note that `fetch()` will block the UI. You can also make this code async:

```
if let user = User.currentUser() {
    user.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (result, error) -> Void in
        if let u = result as? PFUser {
            if let userXP = u["XP"] as? Int {
                self.xpRequiredLabel.text = "\(userXP)/300 XP"
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: still says text is equal to 0

Comment: What type of data is this column in Parse data browser? Is the column name uppercase "XP"?

Answer (score 0):

those are Int values
252 / 300 = 0 when ints invovled
you can do something like

xpRequiredLabel.text = "Float((PFUser.currentUser()!["XP"]))/300.0 XP"

Comment: so what do i need to convert it to a string?

Comment: Ok so I did that now the label says 0.0/300 XP

Comment: let hp: Float = "Float(PFUser.currentUser()!["XP"])
let something: Float = 300.0

let res = hp / something
xpRequiredLabel.text = "/(res)"

Comment: Oh I just realized what your saying I'm not dividing the xp field by 300 XP I'm just trying to display the xp field value but instead of displaying 252 XP its displaying 0 xp.